# zoo column name for single column object

Tags: r, zoo

I have a question on column names in zoo. I usually create zoo objects from a data frame, and I pick up the column(s) from the data frame to be the zoo column(s). What I found is that, if I only specify one column to the zoo object, then the column name will not be taken by zoo. Does that mean it is not considered a "column" in zoo?

Here is an example how I usually do it, with one and two columns.

```
Lines.1 = "Index,dbt
2008-08-20 15:03:18,88.74
2008-08-20 15:08:18,88.74
2008-08-20 15:13:18,86.56
2008-08-20 15:18:18,85.82"

Lines.2 = "Index,dbt,rh
2008-08-20 15:03:18,88.74,18.25
2008-08-20 15:08:18,88.74,17.25
2008-08-20 15:13:18,86.56,18.75
2008-08-20 15:18:18,85.82,19.75"

x =read.table(text = Lines.1, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
y =read.table(text = Lines.2, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

colnames(x)
colnames(y)

library(zoo)
zx = zoo(x[,2], as.POSIXct(x$Index, tz="GMT"))
zy = zoo(y[,2:3], as.POSIXct(y$Index, tz="GMT"))

colnames(zx)
colnames(zy)
```

The result shows as follows:

```
> colnames(zx)
NULL
> colnames(zy)
[1] "dbt" "rh"
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of `[` when used with arrays or data frames; empty dimensions are *dropped*. Consider

```
> x[, 2]
[1] 88.74 88.74 86.56 85.82
> class(x[,2])
[1] "numeric"
> is.data.frame(x[,2])
[1] FALSE
```

In this case the 1-column data frame doesn't need information about which column it is and hence R drops that information and returns the contents of the column as a numeric (in this case) vector, as can be seen above. That vector doesn't have a `colname` attribute and hence **zoo** has nothing to work with.

A solution is to use `drop = FALSE` in the index `x[, 2, drop = FALSE]` as in

```
> zx <- zoo(x[, 2, drop = FALSE], as.POSIXct(x$Index, tz="GMT"))
> zx
                      dbt
2008-08-20 15:03:18 88.74
2008-08-20 15:08:18 88.74
2008-08-20 15:13:18 86.56
2008-08-20 15:18:18 85.82
```

To see why/how this works, look at

```
> x[, 2, drop = FALSE]
    dbt
1 88.74
2 88.74
3 86.56
4 85.82
> is.data.frame(x[, 2, drop = FALSE])
[1] TRUE
```

And note the lack of `colnames` when the default (`TRUE`) is used in the `[` index:

```
> colnames(x[, 2, drop = FALSE])
[1] "dbt"
> colnames(x[, 2, drop = TRUE])
NULL
```

Now read `?'['` for more details.

Comment: Thanks you! I have no idea column can be that complicated. Well, it seems simple now, with this explanation.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is not due to `zoo`. `x[,2]` does not return a data frame but a vector. Hence, there are no columns and no column names.

```
x[,2]
[1] 88.74 88.74 86.56 85.82
```

If you want to return a one-column data frame you can use `x[2]` without a comma or `x[,2, drop = FALSE]`.

```
x[2]
    dbt
1 88.74
2 88.74
3 86.56
4 85.82

x[,2, drop = FALSE]
    dbt
1 88.74
2 88.74
3 86.56
4 85.82
```

The default value of `drop` is `TRUE`. This means that a one-column data frame is automatically transformed into a vector.

Now, it works:

```
zx <- zoo(x[2], as.POSIXct(x$Index, tz="GMT"))
colnames(zx)
[1] "dbt"
```

Comment: Thanks! x[2] is a great shorcut.

Comment: @ery just be careful because a matrix/zoo object is different than a data.frame.  `zy[2]` selects the second row, not the second column.